# Что такое паттерны? Объясните мне как дибилу..(

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Ребят, я много смотрю разные видео на Youtube, и там я увидел что-то про... *Patterns*. Паттерны, я искал **паттерны** - в итоге ***ничё не понял***. Я сам программирую на ***Python***, ***C#*** и не много ***JavaScript***.

Но я в основном изучаю **ООП** в ***C#***. Объясните пожалуйста что такое паттерны и покажите код в ***C#*** где используется *паттерн*.

#### ***НЕ СИНГЛТОН!***

Comment: Паттерн - это общепринятый способ решения типичной задачи. То есть во время программирования возникает много однотипных задач и паттерны - это способы как эти однотипные задачи решать.

Comment: [Видосик](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqgXn7wsPsc) в тему.

Comment: @Bulson моё уважение (снимаю шляпу)

Comment: Я слишком тупенький. Не понимаю(

Comment: Может быть вам поможет то что паттерн переводится как "шаблон"? Знаете значение слова шаблон?

Comment: @axmed2004 это как на wix.com? Там шаблон: интернет-магазин, блог и т.д.. Это типо того, да?

Answer (score 1):

Паттерн как и алгоритм, способ решение задачи. Есть набор задач к которым применим тот или иной алгоритм решения или паттерн. Если алгоритм это `последовательность действий` приводящих к решению, то паттерн `подход` к решению конкретной задачи. Паттерны используются в основном во избежание типичных проблем в программирования.